# Override Skype's "close" (X) button

Tags: windows-7, skype

I use Skype quite frequently and there is something that has bugged me for quite a while. I recently started looking around for a fix to the issue for a relative that also uses Skype. The problem is that Skype treats the "x" button (close) like the minimize button. IMO, This is horrible design but there is no reason complaining about it. What I would like to do (if possible) Is to override the default design for the close button so that it will actually just close the program without just minimizing it to the task bar.

They are currently using windows 7 home edition.

Information already found on the topic:

[Skype Forums](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client-Ideas/Make-an-option-to-close-Skype-when-I-press-the-X-button/idi-p/2890615#M246)

Edit: Had to remove one of the links due to rep. This is something similar to what I'm trying to accomplish.
[Kill applications that minimize instead of closing](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/66191-kill-applications-that-minimze-instead-of-close-like-skype/) It doesn't look complete but I may be able to use what they already have to get some bootleg workaround running.

I attempted to resolve the issue using a fix that I've seen mentioned more than once on their forums.
Tools < Advanced Settings < unclick "Keep Skype in the task bar while I'm signed in"

This has not worked for me (and others by the look of it).

Any workaround to make the button function as it should would be appreciated. I'm not looking for something like "Alt+F4" either. I would like to get this working without keyboard shortcuts so that the computer illiterate I'm fixing this for can get full functionality out of Skype without any extra hassle. I'm not sure if this is something that can be tweaked in the registry but I have no qualms making modifications to it if necessary.

Thank you

Edit: Tyler and Ramhound brought up using right click/context menu from the task bar to close skype. I have already attempted teaching this to my relative and they have trouble comprehending right clicks.

Comment: Your not going to be successful at this task.  It would be easier if you change the way you attempt to close Skype, i.e. actually "quit" Skype through the context menu instead of just minimize it.

Comment: @Ramhound - Thank you for the quick response. I'm assuming this process is handled at a lower level then? I may play around with the API and see if there is something simple I can throw together. Not sure if it is possible but worth a shot.

Comment: To exit Skype completely, right-click the Skype icon in your taskbar and select **Quit**. No other way to do it (gracefully) as far as I know.

Comment: @Tyler - Thank you Tyler, I'm aware of this and tried teaching my grandfather how to do it. He just cannot comprehend a right click for some reason. I probably should have thrown that in there.

Comment: Lol, in that case, write a batch file for him that kills the Skype process. He can double click it to exit skype. `taskkill /f /im skype.exe`

Comment: @Tyler - Now I know he understands double clicks. I could even make a fancy icon that looks like a gigantic X for him... Putting that on my list of possible solutions to try with him lol.

Comment: I don't know if this really works with a program as complex as skype but as a really out-of-the-box (and dirty) workaround you could try something similar to this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9123/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WinForm-project. You embed the whole program into your own and get new buttons that behave as you want them to. I think that demo program would even be enough to test if it works but it might be that you have to program some stuff yourself for the perfect behavior (or style)

Comment: @Syberdoor - That looks pretty nifty. Wouldn't have thought of that... I've embedded browsers and such before but never thought of trying to run Skype inside a separate form. Once I get to try this I'll post the results.

Comment: First, what the purpose is for closing the application completely?   Is it to free up memory, restart the application, become invisible to other users?  Since the purpose of Skype is to receive near-real time notice and communicate, shutting down is similar to only turning your phone on when you want to make an outbound call--you'd never receive a call.  I think there could be a solution, once we understand the purpose better.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the button is determined by the application code. Unless Skype provides an option internally or you modify the application via code or hex editor, you will not be able to accomplish what you are looking for.